# Updating button text when FormView item is Updated

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm still somewhat new to ASP, and can't seem to figure out what the issue is.

When I update an item in FormView, I need the text of a button to change.

I'm using:

```
Protected Sub fvClientInfo_ItemUpdated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.FormViewUpdatedEventArgs) Handles fvClientInfo.ItemUpdated
    btnEditClient.Text = "Edit"
End Sub
```

The line of code is being called (can tell from debug mode), but the button text isn't changing and I have no idea why.

I should make sure to mention that the button is NOT inside the FormView.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Protected Sub btnchange() Handles FormView1.DataBound
    Button1.Text = "Newtxt"
End Sub
```

and add this to your formview

OnDataBound="btnchange"

Comment: The button text is still not updating when the Item gets updated.